# What Func<int,int> behave like this?

Tags: c#

Sample 1:

```
static void DelegateTest()
{
  Func<int, int> test = null;
  for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
  {
    int y = i;
    test = (t) => y;
  }
  Console.WriteLine(test(1)); // This thing prints 1
  //Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Sample 2:

```
static void DelegateTest2()
{
  Func<int, int> test = null;
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
  {
    test = (t) => i;
  }
  // This thing prints 2. I want to know why? 
  //Because 'i' gets out of scope when test(1) gets called and it should print 1
  Console.WriteLine(test(1));
  Console.ReadLine();
```

I want to know why Func get incremented value of i when we call it outside scope?

Comment: Pro Tip: It's considered very rude here to post images of code, rather than the formatted text of the code. Your rep is high enough that you ought to know better by now.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Sorry for Image. Next time i will take care of it.

Answer (score 2):

Because the last value of `i` is `2` for both loops.In the first one, last step is not executed because the loop condition evaluated to *false* because `i` becomes 2.And that's why `y` never assigned to `2`. in the second snippet, your lambda captures the last value of `i` which is `2`, that's why it prints 2.

You are passing `1` to your method but it doesn't matter.Even if you pass a different value you still get the same result.It is all about [closures](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx).

If you still have doubts and you want to make sure about what are the last values of `y` and `i` you can make another simple test:

```
int y = 0;
for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++)
{
    y = k;
}
Console.WriteLine(y); // writes 1

int i = 0;
for(; i < 2; i++) { }

Console.WriteLine(i); // writes 2
```

Comment: I do understand this thing but your for loop create doubt. you have created variable out of for loop so it will not go out of scope. But if you do for(int i=0;i<2;i++) then you will not access it at Console.WriteLine. In my example I have created delegate so does it expand life of I variable so it will not go out of scope.

Comment: @dotnetstep it is not different than  `for(int i=0;i<2;i++)`  I just declare it outside in order to see the last value with Console.WriteLine

Answer (score 0):

In your second sample (actually, in both samples), you create something called a **[Closure](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx)**. A closure is created any time you use a variable as part of a lambda statement or anonymous delegate that is defined outside of that lambda/delegate. This closure **captures** (closes over) the `i` variable in the `for` loop, preventing it from "going out of scope". The `for` loop had to increment that `i` variable one last time to become `2` before the condition to break out of the loop failed, and so you end up with `2` instead of `1`.

The first sample does the same thing with the `y` variable. You still capture/close over the variable and prevent it from going out of scope. However, the `y` variable is never set to `2`. The `i` variable in that sample is still incremented to `2`, but after that point the code does not enter the loop, and so `y` is never set to `2`, such that you still see your expected result of `1`.

In both cases, the `1` value passed to the method is never used, and has no effect.

Comment: C'mon, I would expect you to know this is a duplicate many times over.